# Translation string not working for WooCommerce product up-sells heading

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, gettext

I recently used this bit of code to translate the WooCommerce bits that other translation plugin didn't pick up - however, this code doesn't seem to work on some strings like this one. Any idea why it doesn't work?

Loco translate didn't work on this one, and while the filter code was working on 95% of other untranslated strings, this one remained stubborn.

```
// Alter WooCommerce View Cart Text
add_filter( 'gettext', function( $translated_text ) {
    if ( 'You may also like…' === $translated_text ) {
        $translated_text = 'To moze Ci sie spodobac';
    }
    return $translated_text;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_product_upsells_products_heading` related available filter hook:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_upsells_products_heading', 'filter_product_upsells_products_heading' );
function filter_product_upsells_products_heading( $heading_text ) {
     return 'To moze Ci sie spodobac';
}
```

Or your revised code *(where "…" character requires being replaced with `&hellip;`)*:

```php
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_product_upsells_heading_text', 10, 3 );
function change_product_upsells_heading_text( $translated_text, $original_text, $domain ) {
    if( 'You may also like&hellip;' === $original_text ) {
        $translated_text = 'To moze Ci sie spodobac';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Both ways work.

[image]